# How to Read A Text File on Python and Stop When Encountering A Certain Value and Continue Reading After Value is Encountered

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, break, txt

I have a text file with this format:

```
0   -82.871 2.52531 36.64   138 96.05
0   -76.1014    2.52577 35.36   137 83.9
0   -76.1869    5.57562 35.36   137 62.8
0   -18.1623    -11.6886    386.08  411 200.9
0   -4.62234    -4.91846    325.92  364 252.2
0   -2.52609    -1.63149    325.92  364 85.4
0   -2.52609    -1.63149    112.16  197 48.4
0   -18.1623    -4.91846    -54.24  67  69.55
0   -18.1623    -4.91846    386.08  411 64.55
12345678  1
12345678  2
2   25.2279 -72.3226    48.16   147 221.55
2   28.7109 -70.2263    48.16   147 1587.7
2   76.1009 -63.4562    46.88   146 110.35
2   31.9979 -65.5526    48.16   147 1601.8
2   35.4805 -63.4559    48.16   147 310.25
2   31.9979 -58.7826    49.44   148 492.8
2   35.4805 -56.6859    46.88   146 42.6
2   1.63117 -43.1461    73.76   167 54.55
2   4.91818 -38.4723    76.32   169 75.4
```

I have written a program that skips the entire header with `line = raw_dat.readlines()[7:]` and reads the entire file until it encounters the `magic_number` and breaks the loop:

```
file = 'Runnumber169raw10.txt'
magic_number = '12345678'

event1 = []
x1 = []
y1 = []
z1 = []
tb1 = []
q1 = []
Xnoselection = []
X = []
distanceradius = 0

with open(file, 'r') as raw_dat:
    line = raw_dat.readlines()[7:]
    
    for lines in line:
        lines.split()
        print(lines)
        if lines.split()[0] == magic_number:
            break
```

The issue that I am having with this is that it stops because I added the `break` statement that prevents the loop to continue reading. This `break` statement is necessary for our purposes, because we want to analyze the data by reading through the entire file, stop when it encounters the `magic_number`, stores the values corresponding to the first column values, and then continue reading after the `magic_number`. This is the problem I'm having: continue reading the file and storing the values corresponding to the next 1st column values. I also want to note that this is just a test file; we have a file that has 10000 events (first column runs from 0 to 10000). I have used Pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Runnumber169raw10.txt', sep = '\t', skiprows = 5)
event_series = pd.Series(data['eventno.'])
x_series = pd.Series(data['X'])
y_series = pd.Series(data['Y'])
z_series = pd.Series(data['Z'])
tb_series = pd.Series(data['Tb'])
q_series = pd.Series(data['Q'])

event_data = event_series[event_series == '0']
x_data = x_series[event_series == '0']
y_data = y_series[event_series == '0']
z_data = z_series[event_series == '0']
tb_data = tb_series[event_series == '0']
q_data = q_series[event_series == '0']

event = np.array(event_data)
x = np.array(x_data)
y = np.array(y_data)
z = np.array(z_data)
tb = np.array(tb_data)
q = np.array(q_data)
```

The problem with Pandas is that it looks through the entire file for the values corresponding to the first column values of 0 (in this case). But this is not how I want to read the file. To clarify, I just want to read through the entire file until it encounters the `magic_number`; stop reading the file; store the values corresponding to the values of the first column; and continue reading after the magic number and repeat. Can anyone offer any suggesting regarding this?

Comment: The most trivial solution would be to store the line number `N` where you encounter the `magic_number`, and then re-read the file while skipping the first `N` rows. But I still don't understand why you specifically *need* a `break` instead of simply checking for the magic number, doing something, and then continuing the execution.

Comment: You don't need to reread the file. Just loop through `line[N:]` the second time.

Comment: Would it not be easier to `.read_csv()` the whole file? You can use pandas to isolate the rows before the magic numbers / drop the rows containing the magic numbers?

Comment: This text file is just a test file so that I can test out my program to see if it works. The actual file has 10000 events, and most likely will have 10000+ lines of data. Would I have to create a new loop with ```line[N:]``` each time?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` to get the line indexes while iterating the first time. Then you can restart where you left off.

```
with open(file, 'r') as raw_dat:
    line = raw_dat.readlines()[7:]
    
for index, lines in enumerate(line):
    print(lines)
    if lines[0] == magic_number:
        break

for lines in line[index+1:]:
    # do other stuff
```

Or don't read the entire file into a list, loop over the file lines directly.

```
with open(file, 'r') as raw_dat:
    # skip first 7 lines
    for _ in range(7):
        raw_data.readline()

    for lines in raw_dat:
        print(lines)
        if lines.split()[0] == magic_number:
            break

    for lines in raw_dat:
        # do other stuff
```

Comment: If the file is very large, it would be beneficial to use the file object as a generator, i.e `for index, line in raw_dat`. AFAIK `readlines()` returns a list directly.

Comment: This program doesn't seem to work with my applications.  Applying ```enumerate(line)``` prevents me from getting any values beyond the first two columns. Further, the 2nd column doesn't give me any values pertaining to the column title; it only gives ```'t\'```.

Comment: This shouldn't have any impact on the value of `lines` in the loop. `enumerate()` just adds the index as an additional return value, which is assigned to `index`.

Comment: It sounds like you're not calling `split()`